# Specifying the default database for psql to connect to?

Tags: postgresql, shell, command-line, psql

While using psql, I want to change the initial database connection.

I had a database named "test" as the initial connection.

When running `psql` from the command line my prompt would be `test=#`

After deleting the "test" database, and running `psql` in command line, I get the following error:

```
psql: FATAL:  database "test" does not exist
```

I understand what this means, but how do I go about setting the "postgres" database as the default?

Instead of typing `psql postgres` each time.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can configure the default behavior of `psql` -- and in fact any program using the `libpq` client library -- through environment variables.

In your `~/.bashrc` or similar:

```
export PGDATABASE=postgres
```

The PostgreSQL documentation contains [a complete list](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also need to set other connection params, such as user and password for instance, and as an alternative to multiple env. var as suggested in @willglynn one can provide a file called `.pg_service.conf` in a user's home directory (`$HOME` or `~` on Linux/MacOS) to group connectivity parameters together, as in:

```
[mydb]
host=localhost
port=5432
dbname=mydbname
user=myuser
password=passwd1234
```

A single env. variable can then be set (per @willglynn's answer) as `export PGSERVICE=mydb` to reference the group of connectivity settings thus defined.

- [List of parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) available for use in `.pg_service.conf`
- [.pg_service.conf documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html)